# How to run husky pre-push hook only when pushing to a certain branch of a certain remote?

Tags: git, githooks, husky, git-husky

Say I am working with multiple remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/ettie62/Quicke(fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ettie62/Quicke(push)
public  https://github.com/roslyn80/Quicke(fetch)
public  https://github.com/roslyn80/Quicke(push)
```

with each remote having multiple branches:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  refactor
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/refactor
  remotes/public/dev
  remotes/public/master
```

How can I run the following pre-push hook only when attempting to push to a certain branch of a certain remote, e.g. `public/master`, but not run it when pushing to say `origin/master`:

```
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-push": "CI=true npm test"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That hook might very well run for every branch, so you should call a script which would:

- get the [parameters from the pre-push hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push), as in [husky issue 757](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/757)
- call `npm test` only if the first parameter is `refs/head/public/master`